# OONI Hackathon Berlin

Tags: browsers

I just wanted to ask if I could also go to the "Hackathon" to find out more about the Tor Browser because I'm doing a presentation about it in school.

Comment: All of the event info is available here: https://ooni.torproject.org/post/berlin-hackathon-2016/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic according to https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You could try to go there. Probably there are a couple of Tor-related people there (including myself ;)) who can answer TBB questions.